# How to create a new virtual register in an LLVM machine function pass?

Tags: llvm

I'm creating an LLVM MachineFunctionPass. This is a pre-register-allocation pass. I want to add a new MachineInstr (which I create) at a certain point. I'm using BuildMI() to create the new instruction, and then MachineInstr::addOperand() to fill it in. I want to add a new virtual register as one of the operands. What is the best way to do this?

I've read that MachineRegisterInfo::createVirtualRegister() can be used, but it takes a TargetRegisterClass argument, and I'm not sure how to get that. I haven't had any luck searching the documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a number of ways to obtain that. A couple of the most useful are:

1. To ask your `MachineRegisterInfo` about the class of some existing register you already have. You can obtain the `MachineRegisterInfo` (`MRI`) from a `MachineFunction` by calling the `getRegInfo` method. Then, use `MachineRegisterInfo::getRegClass`.
2. Ask your `TargetLowering::getRegClassFor`. You can give it a `MVT`. See `include/llvm/Target/TargetLowering.h` for more details.

Grepping for the above methods through the LLVM source code should provide you with plenty of usage examples.

Comment: Thanks; that's very helpful. However, I don't have an existing register in this case. Regarding the TargetLowering::getRegClassFor(), am I correct in thinking that I need to give it an EVT which I construct via EVT::getIntegerVT()? (This is for a 128-bit register; I want it to eventually turn into something like xmm0 after register allocation.) I'm again a bit stumped on how to get the arguments to pass to getIntegerVT(). It takes an LLVMContext, which I am not sure where to get.

Comment: I was wondering if it would be reasonable to do something like this to get the TargetRegisterClass: MachineFunction::getTarget().getInstrInfo()->getRegClass(myMachineInstr->getDesc(), 0 , MachineFunction::getTarget().getRegisterInfo())

Comment: @user2755615: a context can be obtained from a module, function, etc. In many cases you also have the global context. Grep for `getContext` in the LLVM code-base.